# How to reverse and sort files in Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to take files in a directory and reverse them and then sort them alphabetically.
So that
Cat
Dog
So the output Would be 
God
Tac

Comment: Are you actually trying to rename the files or you just want to list them like that?

Comment: And in what environment are you doing this? So _where_?

Comment: More details are needed since mind-reading is not a widely prevalent skill. She'll script or another language? What do you mean by reversing and sorting? What have you tried do far; post that code. Providing entire algorithms or writing whole coursework programs for free is not SO mission.

Answer (score 10):

If you use terminal write:

```
ls -r
```

It show you your files and directories in reversed order. 
I don't know what kind of Graphical Interface you use. In Gnome you must show files as a list and sort by name (clicking it) diminishing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with files and folder names, not to change their names, I hope this will help you:

```
ls your-path | rev | sort
```